# I can't find cwagent metrics on aws console (cloudwatch agent)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch, endpoint

I installed cloudwatch agent at EC2 and checked 'running' status.

> install process

(EC2 has EIP and VPC has internet gateway and routing table (0.0.0.0/0 -> igw-xxx)

(create role-CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy and connect ec2)

(sudo su)

(wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/redhat/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm)

(rpm -U ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm)

(/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard)

(/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file://opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json -s)

(/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -m ec2 -a status)

(check status -> running)

but I can't find cwagent metrics on aws console.

I don’t know why not.

now VPC has vpn connection and dx connection…
and has vpc endpoint

Can this be a problem? (routingtable, security group)

but I did download agent file…. in other word.. can use internet..

thank you.

config.json

```
{
        "agent": {
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "run_as_user": "cwagent"
        },
        "metrics": {
                "append_dimensions": {
                        "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
                        "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
                        "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
                        "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
                },
                "metrics_collected": {
                        "disk": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "used_percent"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                                "resources": [
                                        "*"
                                ]
                        },
                        "mem": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "mem_used_percent"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 10
                        }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup AWS CloudWatch's agent at Ubuntu to get (correct) custom metrics like cpu, memory and disk usage %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242033/how-to-setup-aws-cloudwatchs-agent-at-ubuntu-to-get-correct-custom-metrics-li)