# How to setup AWS CloudWatch's agent at Ubuntu to get (correct) custom metrics like cpu, memory and disk usage %

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm running an AWS EC2 m5.large (a none burstable instance). I have setup one of AWS CloudWatch's default metrics (CPU %) + some custom metrics (memory + disk usage) in my dashboard.

But when I compare the numbers CloudWatch report to me they are pretty far from then actually usage of the Ubuntu 20.04 server when I log in to it...

Actual usage:

```
CPU: ~ 35 %
Memory: ~ 33 %
```

CloudWatch report:

```
CPU ~ 10 %
Memory: ~ 50-55
```

https://www.screencast.com/t/o1nAnOFjVZW

I have followed AWS own instructions to add the metrics for memory and disk usage (Because CloudWatch doesn't out of the box have access to O/S level stuff): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html

When numbers are so far from each other - then it would be impossible to setup useful alarms and notifications. I can't believe that is what AWS wants to provide to the people who chose to followed their original instructions?
The only thing with match exactly is the disk usage %.

Comment: Can you clarify what are you using? CloudWatch scripts which are obsolete and no longer updated or  [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)? The link you provided is about the scripts.

Comment: I'm using the script - should it not work?

Comment: Which metric aggregation are you using? Max, min, average? The script will be calling the APIs on the host to get these metrics and then push them.

Comment: @mokugo-devops The metrics are set to the default of "Average".

Comment: The scripts are no-longer maintained and shouldn't be used with new architectures. So their current accuracy could be problematic. If you can, I would check with CW Agent, which is the recommended way by AWS to collect the metrics.

Comment: When I first look and compared the CPU % usage I thought to myself -  that CloudWatch/the script report the actual CPU % usage of the physical server (it would make sense now when the number is so much lower 10% vs. 35%). But then I looked at the memory usage and it is up-side-down... which made me confused...

Comment: Also do I need to uninstall the script before installing the Agent?

Comment: No need to uninstall for tests. CW Agent will create a new namespace in CW metrics called CWAgent. Thus its metrics will go there. If it works, then later you can consider what to do with the scripts.

Comment: I will try to follow the instructions in regards to the agent and return to you guys! Thank you for your help so far! FYI: I read about the agent before - but the script seemed as an faster option at first ... but not in the end I guess ...lol

Comment: Btw...The CPU % usage is standard for all EC2 instances (not reported via the legacy script) - So why is this number of as well?

Comment: By default CW uses hypervisor to get its CPU stats. CW Agent will do this from the inside of the instance. Small discrepancies are expected between what OS reports to the agant and what hypervisor measures.

Comment: Also, please note that Amazon CloudWatch displays a calculated figure (eg Average CPU) _over a time period_ (eg 5 minutes), which will not exactly match with a specific CPU measure at one moment in time.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I know - But if you look at the CPU % usage... https://www.screencast.com/t/o1nAnOFjVZW CloudWatch shows an average of ~ 10 % for the latest hour and the server shows a min. of 35% for the latest minute... The server load is constant... it is only running some back-end services (not a web server with requests etc)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### HOW TO INSTALL AWS AGENT AT UBUNTU 20.04 (NEWER WAY INSTEAD OF THE OLD SCRIPT: "CloudWatchMonitoringScripts")

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html

```
1. sudo wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/debian/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
2. sudo dpkg -i -E ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
3. sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard
4. Go through all the steps in the wizard (The result is saved here: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json)
```

Hint: I answered:

```
 - Default to most questions and otherwise:
 - NO  --> Do you want to store the config in the SSM parameter store? (Because when I answered YES it failed later on because of some permission-issue and I didn't know how to make it happy and I don't think I need SSM in regards to this)
 - YES --> Do you want to turn on StatsD daemon?
 - YES --> Do you want to monitor metrics from CollectD?
 - NO  --> Do you have any existing CloudWatch Log Agent?
```

Now to prevent this error: Error parsing /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml, open /usr/share/collectd/types.db: no such file or directory
https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-cloudwatch-user-guide/issues/1

```
5. sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/collectd/
6. sudo touch /usr/share/collectd/types.db
7. sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json -s
8. /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -m ec2 -a status

{
  "status": "running",
  "starttime": "2020-06-07T10:04:41+00:00",
  "version": "1.245315.0"
}
```

9. https://www.screencast.com/t/42VWgoS88Z (Create IAM role, add policies and make it the server default role).
10. https://www.screencast.com/t/fAUUHCPe (CloudWatch new custom metrics)
11. https://www.screencast.com/t/8J0Saw0co (data match OK now)
12. https://www.screencast.com/t/x0PxOa799 (data match OK now)

I realized - that the second I login to the machine the CPU % usage goes up from 10 % to 30% and stays there (of course some increase was to be expected - but not that much in my opinion) which in my case explains the big difference earlier...I honestly don't now if this way in more precise than the older script - but this should be the right way to do it in year 2020 :-) And you get access to 179 custom metrics when selecting "Advanced" during the wizard (even though only few would be valuable to most people)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I wonder why AWS hasn't listed all these important commands.

Comment: @Lokesh You are welcome my friend! I'm only happy to make your and other people life's easier after I have been struggling for hours or even days some times (and it is personally also a great way to remember how you solved something once and not forgetting about it again). AWS docs are massive and often tiresome ...and of course they also make a living out of premium-memberships so you can pay to make them help you ;)

Comment: Try one :

mkdir -p /usr/share/collectd/
touch /usr/share/collectd/types.db

Not working .

Try two :
Removed collectd related configuration from cloud-watch agent configuration .
Not working as it's always expecting it and showing the collectd section is missing .

Try Three :
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y collectd

Not worked , installation package not found .

Note : I am using : FROM debian:latest as build

Comment: @Forhad Sounds to me like you don't use SUDO?

Comment: @PabloDK  Yes, you are right. It's already fixed.